# PHP inserting incorrect password

Tags: php, mysql, user-permissions

I'm trying to create a mysql user account at runtime in PHP7.0, granted access to a single database, also created at runtime. 
I'm currently using:

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $admin_account, $password);

$setup = [
    /* create database */
    sprintf('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s;', $dbName),
    /* grant admin */
    sprintf("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %s.* TO '%s'@'%s' WITH GRANT OPTION;", $dbName, $admin_account, $admins_remote_ip),
    /* add user */
    sprintf("CREATE USER '%s'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%s';", $dbUsername, $dbPassword),
    /* THIS WAS ADDED AS A FIX TO NO AVAIL */
    sprintf("UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('%s') WHERE user='%s'", $dbPassword, $dbUsername),
    /* grant retailer*/
    sprintf("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %s.* TO '%s'@'localhost';", $dbName, $dbUsername),
    /* flush */
    "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;",
];



foreach ($setup as $query) {
    if (false == $this->mysqli->query($query)) {
        $error = $this->mysqli->error;
        return $error;
    }
}
```

All of the statements execute without an error, everything appears to be where it should, however the non-admin user gets a mysql->error;

> Connect failed: Access denied for user 'dbUsername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

If I do this;

```
> mysql -u admin_account -p
update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('dbPassword') where user='dbUsername';
```

Then the connection works and all is well.
Please help.

*edit: I've removed the transactional behaviour, removing it from the live code didn't fix the issue. It appears that the password string is being altered somewhere between PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Have you checked whether `mysqli` returns any error messages?

Comment: What’s the `UPDATE mysql.user …` statement supposed to be good for? The one above that, `CREATE USER … IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` should have already set that password for the user when it was created …?

Comment: Just a heads up - transactions and DDL statements don't really work together.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking for errors, and the  UPDATE mysql.user line was added to fix or further check for errors.

Comment: And what if your password has a single quote in it? Please for the love of security escape your input with `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Also note that you can perform the grant in a single query: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %s.* TO '%s'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%s'` will create the user, grant access and set the password all in one go.

Comment: Is $dbPassword set to 'dbPassword'?  I'd agree it is an issue with password, but is your variable set correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, transaction control commands are used with the DML commands such as - INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. If you use them while creating tables or dropping them, the result may depends on the auto-commit mode. By default, [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) automatically commits the changes permanently to the [database](/questions/tagged/database).

If you read the article "[How Popular Databases Deal with DDL Commands in Transactions](https://www.datasunrise.com/blog/how-popular-rdbmss-deal-with-ddl-commands-in-transactions/)", you will notice that not all databases are able to rollback DDL changes. They do support DDL commands transactionality but not for all commands.

Also you will find in the [MySQL Internals Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transactions-notes-on-ddl-and-normal-transaction.html) that DDL statements and operations with nontransactional engines do not "register" in the transaction lists. Check wich engine you are using (InnoDB or MyISAM).

I have reproduced the example purely in [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) and found that FLUSH must be the cause. This is confirmed in the manual. [The FLUSH statement causes an implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html).

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS StackOverflow;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  StackOverflow.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'customer'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'customer';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON StackOverflow.* TO 'customer'@'localhost';
COMMIT;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In the table mysql.user the 'customer' has been created without rights.
In the table mysql.db the 'customer' and 'admin' have been created with rights.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, removing the transaction from the above code didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it's true that most databases have restrictions. But for debugging purposes and learning, you might to enable general log in mysql (which will log ALL queries).

It will create big overhead and doesn't fit production requirements, but its fast and easy way to fix bugs in development environment.

Using @foxfabi DB example's name, got the following output from your queries:

```
2019-01-28T10:08:44.791816Z    55 Connect   root@localhost on  using Socket
2019-01-28T10:08:44.792076Z    55 Query CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS StackOverflow
2019-01-28T10:08:44.792556Z    55 Query GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON StackOverflow.* TO 'root'@'1.1.1.1' WITH GRANT OPTION
2019-01-28T10:08:44.792839Z    55 Quit
```